# How do I switch teams?

Tags: overwatch

Sometimes, I don't want to play Attackers and play Defenders, and when I don't want to play Defenders I want to play Attackers.  When I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> I can see what members compose each team as well as how many players they have.

In some instances, I can clearly tell the other team has 2 or 1 less players than our team. If I want to switch teams to join the other team, how can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, there is **no way** for a player to change between Attackers and Defenders when they want to, whether there's an open slot on the other team or not. If one really wanted to (have a chance of) changing teams, they could leave the game, and rejoin, however, this affects your Win/Loss ratio, adding a negative point to your ratio.

Odds are, there's little chance for this to be implemented, as Overwatch is a six vs. six objective-based game, if players were given the option to switch teams to their liking, it could easily be abused to win by switching teams as one team does better than the other.

Comment: It's not about abuse, it's about "the game is exactly 6v6".  The only time switching would even be possible is if someone on the other team left, and you want to switch to replace them.  That use-case sounds extremely rare, so I doubt they'll ever support it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to change teams in Overwatch.

This is common in hero objective based games, as members of a losing side would be allowed to jump to the winning team, if exploited correctly.

If you believe the feature would make the game more enjoyable, voice your concerns on [the Overwatch forum](http://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/). Blizzard have already proven their attention to suggestion and complaint, previously altering a characters pose in response to forum controversy<sup>[source](http://kotaku.com/blizzard-removing-overwatch-butt-pose-after-fan-complai-1767613551)</sup>.

Comment: It's actually pretty uncommon to be unable to change teams; TF2 allows you to readily switch teams, Dirty Bomb does the same. Only in situations such as competitive environments where obviously you can't switch teams would your statement make sense.

Comment: @O-O, I experience the opposite, though I do not play as many similar games. DOTA and LoL are two examples. I have clarified my answer

Comment: Ah, okay, that makes more sense if you're talking about Dota, LoL, HoS, etc.

Comment: @O-O, see my inclusion regarding forums. Make a stand on there, if you think it would be a good addition. The game is still in beta; If enough people back it, Blizzard will consider it.

Comment: TF2 and such also have variable team sizes. Overwatch will refuse to start a match until exactly 12 people have been found.